# Array of objects in state not updating correctly in React app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-state, react-state-management

I am trying to make a list of messages and update it as I add more, I think I'm missing something but can't tell what it is.

App has 2 components - Messages and SendMessage, Messages is mapping over an array of Message Component. SenMessage has a form that will update the array store in messages state.

Thanks for any help in advance.

App.js

```
function App() {
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([{name: 'ken', 'message': "hayyy"},{name: 'kendra', 'message': "hayyy"}])

const handleSend = (message) => {
    const newMessages = [...messages];
    newMessages.push(message);
    setMessages(newMessages);
    console.log(message)
  }

return (
<div className="App">
<Messages messages={messages} />
<SendMessage onSend={handleSend}/>
</div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Messages.js

```
const Messages = (props) => {
const messages = props.messages.map((message, index) => {
    return (
        <Message 
            key={index}
            name={message.name}
            message={message.message}
        />
    )})
return (
    <div>
    {messages}
    </div>
)}
export default Messages;
```

Message.js

```
const Message = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="Message">
          <p className="message">{props.message}</p>
          <p className="name">{props.name}</p>
        </div>
    )}

export default Message;
```

SendMessage.js

```
const SendMessage = (props) => {
    const [inputMessage, setInputMessage] = useState('')
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        props.onSend(inputMessage);
        setInputMessage('')
    }
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setInputMessage(event.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div className="SendMessage">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="enter message" 
                value={inputMessage}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <button>Send</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    )}
export default SendMessage;
```

Comment: What is the issue? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: @DrewReese When I click Send button the new message shows up in the array but it shows up empty.

Comment: What do you mean it "shows up in the array but it shows up empty"?

Comment: You don't seem to be sending any `message` when you're calling `handleSend`

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, the message seems to console log correctly but it doesnt seem to show on the Messages component when I send the message. it just shows blank.

Comment: Ah, I see now, `inputMessage` and `message` are strings, but you are expecting to render message objects with `name` and `message` properties.

Comment: @DrewReese ok this makes a bit more sense now. Should I change the state on the SendMessage component? I think that is where the issue is?

Comment: That really all depends on where `name` comes from, but assuming you already "know" who is typing and sending the messages it, IMO, makes more sense to keep your state as simple as possible and only construct the "message" object when updating the `messages ` array state in `App`. I don't know what `name` means here though, perhaps it is the person the message is being sent to.

Comment: @DrewReese name would be my name that I would get from a login form that I have yet to build, in this case, I could probably just add another input to sendMessage for now to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue that I see here is that in the `SendMessage` component, you are saving the state to a string and trying to send to a `handleSend` function which expects an object with keys like `name` and `message`.

Thus you can update your `handleSend` function like this:

```js
const handleSend = (message) => {
    const formattedMsg = { name: 'Some Name', message };
    const newMessages = [...messages, formattedMsg];
    setMessages(newMessages);
}
```

Also as a general practice use optional chaining whenever you are trying to use nested keys from objects. If you were using TypeScript, then this problem wouldn't occur in the first place since most probably you'd annotate the args with specific types. But here what we can do is atleast provide an optional chain(using `?` operator) and handle the case where no messages exists.

```js
const messages = props.messages.map((message, index) => (
        <Message 
            key={index}
            name={message?.name}
            message={message?.message}
        />
));

if (!messages) {
 return (
   <p>No messages...</p>
 )
}
```

[Edit] I now see that @DrewReese has commented a similar answer. Didn't see it before posting.